# How to set model class data on a fragment?

Tags: android, parsing, android-fragments, fragment

I am using a model class Model_userDetails to parse data from the server and save in it .

```
public class Model_userDetails {
    public   String name;
    public   String email;
    public   String mobile;
}
```

Now i want yo use this model class to display its data on my fragment .

I am using this syntax

```
t_email.setText(model_userDetails.email.toString());
```

in my fragment but the app crashes and gives null pointer exception

What should i do ?

I have used log so that i can see whats happening

```
JSONArray message = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                boolean success = false;

                for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject temp = message.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        if (temp.getString("success").equals("1")) {
                            success = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (i != 0 && success) {
                        Model_userDetails modalIUserDetails = new Model_userDetails();
                        modalIUserDetails.email = temp.getString("email");
                        Log.e("ABCdata",temp.getString("email"));
                        Log.e("ABCdata",temp.getString("name"));
                        modalIUserDetails.name = temp.getString("name");
                        modalIUserDetails.mobile = temp.getString("mobile");
                        modalIUserDetails.state = temp.getString("state");
                        modalIUserDetails.district = temp.getString("district");
                        modalIUserDetails.block = temp.getString("block");
                        modalIUserDetails.village = temp.getString("village");
                        modalIUserDetails.designation = temp.getString("designation");

                        Log.e("ABC1","adding");
                        arrayList.add(modalIUserDetails);
                        Log.e("ABC1",modalIUserDetails.email);


                    }


                }

                Log.e("ABC1","returning");
                return ; 


02-28 16:18:27.892 20959-20959/katheria.vhp E/ABC1: shekhar.borntofly@gmail.com
02-28 16:18:27.892 20959-20959/katheria.vhp E/ABC2: shekhar.borntofly@gmail.com
02-28 16:18:27.893 20959-20959/katheria.vhp E/ABC: endpoints
02-28 16:18:27.894 20959-20959/katheria.vhp E/ABClast: shekhar.borntofly@gmail.com
02-28 16:18:30.532 20959-20959/katheria.vhp E/ABC1: data parser
02-28 16:18:30.532 20959-20959/katheria.vhp E/ABCdata: shekhar.borntofly@gmail.com
02-28 16:18:30.532 20959-20959/katheria.vhp E/ABCdata: Shekhar Singh
02-28 16:18:30.532 20959-20959/katheria.vhp E/ABC1: adding
02-28 16:18:30.532 20959-20959/katheria.vhp E/ABC1: shekhar.borntofly@gmail.com
02-28 16:18:30.533 20959-20959/katheria.vhp E/ABC1: returning
02-28 16:18:30.533 20959-20959/katheria.vhp E/ABC1: returned
```

Comment: Atleast post your stacktrace.

Comment: it is throwing null pointer because your email might be null. or you haven't initialized your model properly.

Comment: Null pointer exception can only be occur here if your model is null and you are taking value from object.

Comment: Model is not null